# How to get a value from a dictionary which might be None in python

Tags: python

There is a dictionary object named my_dic.

```
my_dic = {'name': 'tom'}
print(f"The name is {my_dic.get('name')}")
```

In case my_dic is None, there will be an expected exception as `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

How to make one line code to get None in case my_dic is None, otherwise return by get().

Thanks.

Comment: `try/except` block?

Comment: Yay! Another homework question intended to see if the student has learned the basics of the Python language.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is not a homework question.
I was looking for the shortest solution without lots of if else with None.
Yet, I think Chris and wjandrea's first solution is the best atm.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a conditional expression to handle the case where `my_dic` is `None`.

```
>>> my_dic = None
>>> print(f"The name is {my_dic.get('name') if my_dic else None}")
The name is None
>>> print(f"The name is {None if my_dic is None else my_dic.get('name')}")
The name is None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dic = {'name': 'tom'} # return name 
# my_dic = None # return None if my_dic is None
print(f"The name is {my_dic.get('name')}" if my_dic is not None else None)
```